# An example of non-homeomorphic surfaces, $S_1, S_2$, such that $S_1 \times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $S_2 \times [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I'm just reviewing the questions I couldn't answer in an exam I gave for my Topology course, one of the questions asked me the following:

**To give an example of two compact connected surfaces $S_1, S_2$, possibly with boundary, such that $S_1$ is not homeomorphic to $S_2$, but $S_1 \times [0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $S_2 \times [0,1]$.**

I would be grateful if someone could give me an answer, or even an approach to this problem, because I'm drawing a complete blank

Comment: See this (example of Sergei Ivanov): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products

Comment: Can you explain what 'thickening of a torus' means?

Comment: The torus is a sheet of zero thickness-the boundary of a donut.  The thickened torus he talks of is the outer 3mm of a donut.   Another way to think of it is to take a thick walled cylinder, bend it around and join the ends.  It has one hole through the middle, the usual donut hole, and one around the major circle.

Comment: @Ross, I think I understand your construction, but could you explain how one realises $T^2 \times [0,1]$ in such a way? As the below answer says, it is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so what sort of "projection " the map we're looking at for this realisation?

Comment: And coming to the suggested homeomorphism to the said spaces in the response by Sergei, I'm trying to understand the suggested pretzel like boundary, because as far as I can see. We now have a surface with 1 handle, and another with 2

Comment: Each shape is a blob with two holes through it.  One is just a plate that you drill through twice.  The thick torus I described above.  It also has two holes.  The fact that they are linked does not matter.