# Recommendations for books which covers Surfaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, surfaces

I'm looking for books which have a good portion on Surfaces. I know Hatcher's Algebraic Topology has a decent part where he does venture into them. But I was looking for something more, surfaces + covering maps etc. Something that would give me the tools necessary to approach and answer questions like these:
[Covering map between orientable compact connected surfaces without boundary with genus g](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816786/covering-map-between-orientable-compact-connected-surfaces-without-boundary-with) and [An example of non-homeomorphic surfaces, S1,S2, such that S1×[0,1] is homeomorphic to S2×[0,1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816110/an-example-of-non-homeomorphic-surfaces-s-1-s-2-such-that-s-1-times-0-1)

I have been unable to find a good (algebraic) topology book which does that. Any recommendations are helpful!